# Is there an upgrade gem to prawn to covert odf (.odt)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-6, prawn

I've been using the awesome prawn gem in my last few project, but this time I have to covert a odt file (in odf format) to PDF.
I know that there are many gems that can do this, for example docsplit and others, but since I am already using prawn to generate other PDFs in the same app I would really like to know if I could get a way without adding yet another pdf creator type gem...

Does anyone know any resources that could help? Or at least a (really) simple gem that coverts odt to PDF (without possibly having to install anything)?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

No, Prawn can't do that. Prawn is just a library for programmatically generating PDF documents.

Best way would be using LibreOffice in a head-less fashion to convert ODF files into PDF.